# how to check whether a string has exactly n words in mysql

Tags: mysql

Like my table consist of name street and city .
My query is to find customer name whose street address match any string of 1)exactly 3 character 2)at least 3 character

Comment: What you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use String function - Length.

```
1)Exactly 3 character
SELECT customer_name,street_address FROM TABLE WHERE LENGTH(street_address ) = 3

2)At least 3 character
SELECT customer_name,street_address FROM TABLE WHERE LENGTH(street_address ) >= 3
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It should help you: `WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a_%_%'`   Finds any values that start with "a" and are at least 3 characters in length